# Nginx, GET and POST solution for "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy

I'm trying to create a SSL proxy for a web management console running on localhost and having no SSL support.

Here is my config:

```
server {
  listen                  111.222.1.1:8443 ssl;
  server_name             admin.company.com;

  ssl_certificate         tls/ssl.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key     tls/ssl.key;

  proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_hide_header       X-Powered-By;

  #error_page 497         https://admin.company.com:8443$request_uri;

  location / {
    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
}
```

The proxied service is quite sophisticated and uses a lot of Post/Redirect/Get operations, network monitor shows they're all involving "**http**://admin.company.com:8443" and thus causing the subj.

Adding `error_page 497` (commented out) solves GETs and redirects, but makes POSTs impossible. Is there any solution to this, one IP and one port configuration, which would proxy both GET and POST requests?

**UPD:**
The application behind proxy is a Java servlet running in the insecure mode, so I believe this is where "http" comes from, it simply takes proxied hostname and builds up URLs with "http" explicitly set.

Comment: The easy (and correct) way is to fix the application.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, out of my reach. So the answer is "this is impossible"?

Comment: Well, you are not sending X-Forwarded-Proto upstream, so doing that might help, if the application supports it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thanks, but X-Forwarded-Proto doesnt work, looks like it's Java container responsible for "http", see my update.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment. But I would suggest you check your upstream, and also check other nginx conf files and make sure that they are targeting specific ips and not a wildcard e.g.  listen                  *:8443 ssl; or something. This way it doesn't fallback.

Comment: No wildcards in use, 100%. I believe that this "http" is generated by the app which is basically a Java servlet without SSL configuration in `web.xml`, so the app "thinks" it runs in the insecure mode. Rep added))